# Next Auth getSession() returns undefined| null

Tags: next.js, next-auth

i have the following code

```js
export const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
  const { data, status } = useSession()
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>()

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccessToken(() => data?.user.accessToken)
  }, [data])

  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `${SERVER_LOCALHOST}/api/v1`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  })
}
```

Basically i don't want the accesstoken extracted from session to be null because this will cause the requests to be posted with `undefined` in the authorization header...
i have tried this

```js
export const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
  const { data, status } = useSession()
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>()

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccessToken(() => data?.user.accessToken)
  }, [data])

  if (status == 'authenticated') {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: `${SERVER_LOCALHOST}/api/v1`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to do  the trick.Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Make sure that the code is executed on the client side, and wrap `pages/_app.js` with `<SessionProvider />` https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved it, I hope so. I made a similar code to yours, but it does not go around an useEffect (because it will make things go brrr)
Anyways, what I did to extract and make it work correctly (for now) is:

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession()
const Request = async () => {} //this is your fetch request
if(status === 'authenticated'){
   Request()  //you call the fetch function
}
```

I dont know why Next.js needs to make two requests (the first loading, and the second authenticated or unauthenticated), because the first one always mess up your api call even if you wrap your code correctly on a Provider...
Anyways my code is simple to explain. If the status changes to authenticated then it makes the API call and the data could be saved on a useState function so on...
Still trying different ways to fix it or make it better...